# Angular 5 using material, jasmine karma test fail with mat-icon

Tags: angular, angular-material, karma-jasmine, angular-material2

I'm trying to run jasmine karma  with

```
ng test
```

Surprise with all the issues with Angular Materials.   I see example of OLDER version of material many months ago when it was called `md-icon` instead of `mat-icon` etc...

Thus this doesn't fix the errors thrown

```
MaterialModule.forRoot()
```

Error

> mat-icon is not a known element  angular material

Comment: It would be good if we could see one of the unit tests you are having an issue with.

Comment: May have to import MatIconModule

Comment: in your `*.spec` file for unit testing you have to import MatIconModule as Naykam said and you also have to import: `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`  `import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";`. after that you have to add following in : `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]` in: `TestBed.configureTestingModule({....})`. Give it a tray

Comment: Try to import the icon module, MaterialModule was depracated

Comment: already importing MatIconModule ....

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I was experiencing the same issues testing Material components.

Thanks to [k.vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5310217/k-vincent) for providing the correct answer for me in the comments.

For components using Material, ensure your *.spec file looks similar to this:

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

...

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ MyComponent ],
        schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));
```

Comment: this is still failing for me in Angular 7

Comment: Yes, it is failing for me too.

Comment: Can anyone please explain "the why" of this problem, so I don't just copy/paste and continue on being ignorant.

Comment: CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA Defines a schema that allows an NgModule to contain Non-Angular elements named with dash case (`-`) and Element properties named with dash case (`-`). So, I think it just ignores that they are special elements at all. I actually had to remove MatIconModule from my TestingModule, then it worked.

Comment: The above solution in combination with removing MatIconModule from my TestingModule did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

My test were also failing for *can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'*; *if 'app-forgot-password' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module*; *if 'mat-card' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module*. In spec file i added imports of ReactiveFormsModule and CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA and it worked.

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ ForgotPasswordComponent ],
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
.compileComponents();
}));
```

Then i had another error: *Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'*. I could fix it by adding RouterTestingModule in the spec file:

```
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';

beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    RouterTestingModule
  ],
  declarations: [ LoginFormComponent ]
})
.compileComponents();
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was simply missing the `MatIconTestingModule`:

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ...,
        MatIconTestingModule
      ],
      ...
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });
```

Comment: I like this a lot more than setting `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Angular 9 and by taking clues from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60209355/521554) I figured out a way to render the icons. The solution was to find where the application registred the icons and then call that registration explicitly. There is a caveat for `MatIconRegistry` needing `HttpClientModule`.

Background:
From `app.component.ts` I am using my service `IconService` and on that I call my `registerIcons` method.

Abbreviated `IconService`:

```
constructor(
  private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
  private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
) { }

public registerIcons(): void {
  ...
  this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(key, this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(iconUrl));
});
```

So In my test I:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    MatIconModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    // MatIconRegistry, <- strangely enough not needed.
    {
      provide: DomSanitizer,
      useValue: {
        sanitize: (ctx: any, val: string) => val,
        bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl: (val: string) => val,
      },
    },
    IconService,
  ]
})
  .compileComponents();
```

and

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.inject(IconService).registerIcons();
});
```

---

iconsEnums.ts:

```
export enum Icon {
    cloud = 1,
    drop,
    rain,
}
```

iconService.ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IconService {

  constructor(
    private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) { }

  public registerIcons(): void {
    const iconValues = this.getEnumValues(Icon);
    iconValues.forEach(key => {
      const iconUrl = (`../assets/icons/${key}-icon.svg`);
      this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(key, this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(iconUrl));
    });
  }

  private getEnumValues(enumType: any): string[] {
    return Object.values(enumType).filter(v => typeof v === 'string') as string[];
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you give the code you put in the service plz ? because i don't know from where come 'key' and 'iconUrl'. Is that a generic solution or do i have to put all the icons and iconurl in an array ? Thx

Comment: so with your solution, we have to save all the icons we want to see in test in assets/icons ?

Comment: @user3659739 Yes. You also have to name them "cloud-icon.svg", "drop-icon.svg" and "rain-icon.svg". If it does not suit you, adapt `('../assets/icons/${key}-icon.svg')` to your needs. A nice feature of the code is that you only have to add the file to the folder to have Angular pick it up, and you only have to add an item to `Icon` enum to use it in your code.

Answer (score -1):

I am using Angular 9 and by taking clues from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61131907/521554) I ended up copying the very [source file from `FakeMatIconModule`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/icon/testing/fake-icon-registry.ts) and use it like so:

```
imports: [
  MatIconModule,
  MatIconTestingModule,
],
```

It does not render the icons though.