# Angular 6 unit testing component with DomSanitizer dependency

Tags: angular, unit-testing, sanitization

In a unit test to just create (instantiate) a component that has a `DomSanitizer` dependency, how does one mock / stub this dependency?

Because `DomSanitizer` is an `Abstract` class, I have no idea what the method signature of `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` really looks like.

And if it's not intended to mock / stub `DomSanitizer`, how should one proceed to inject the actual implementation iso the abstract class?

actual statement in the component looks like:

```js
this.trustedString = <string>this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(trustedHTML);
```

`TestBed` setup looks like:

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      // other modules
    ],
    providers: [
      {
        provide: DomSanitizer,
        useValue: {
          bypassSecurityTrustHtml: () => 'safeString'
        }
      },
      // more providers
    ],
    declarations: [ TheComponent ],
    schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
  })
    .compileComponents();
}));
```

The specific error that I'm getting in Karma in Chrome (not headless) is this:

`TypeError: view.root.sanitizer.sanitize is not a function`

> error properties: Object({ ngDebugContext: DebugContext_({ view: Object({ def: Object({ factory: Function, nodeFlags: 16793601, rootNodeFlags: 1, nodeMatchedQueries: 0, flags: 0, nodes: [ Object({ nodeIndex: 0, parent: null, renderParent: null, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 0, flags: 1, childFlags: 16793601, directChildFlags: 16777217, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object({  }), matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object({  }), ngContentIndex: null, childCount: 5, bindings: [  ], bindingFlags: 0, outputs: [  ], element: Object({ ns: null, name: null, attrs: [  ], template: null, componentProvider: null, componentView: null, componentRendererType: null, publicProviders: null({  }), allProviders: null({  }), handleEvent: Function }), provider: null, text: null, query: null, ngContent: null }), Object({ nodeIndex: 1, parent: Object({ nodeIndex: 0, parent: null, renderParent: null, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 0, flags: 1, childFlags: 16793601, directChildFlags: 16777217 ...
>       at 
>       at setElementProperty (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:8237:61)
>       at checkAndUpdateElementValue (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:8189:13)
>       at checkAndUpdateElementInline (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:8136:24)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:10477:20)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:10443:16)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:11076:38)
>       at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:11062:13)
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ng:///DynamicTestModule/ConversationMessageComponent.ngfactory.js:84:5)
>       at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:11054:21)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:10430:14)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As a workaround, try add `sanitize: () => 'safeString',`

```
...
useValue: {
  sanitize: () => 'safeString',
  bypassSecurityTrustHtml: () => 'safeString'
}
...
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to preserve the value, use:

```
{
  provide: DomSanitizer,
  useValue: {
    sanitize: (ctx: any, val: string) => val,
    bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl: (val: string) => val,
  },
}
```